# Project Euler problem #11 - Largest product in a grid

Tags: python, programming-challenge, matrix, numpy

I have recently solved the following [Project Euler problem](https://projecteuler.net/problem=11):

> In the 20×20 grid below, four numbers along a diagonal line have been marked in red [*here bold*].
>
> `08 02 22 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08`
>   `49 49 99 40 17 81 18 57 60 87 17 40 98 43 69 48 04 56 62 00`
>   `81 49 31 73 55 79 14 29 93 71 40 67 53 88 30 03 49 13 36 65`
>   `52 70 95 23 04 60 11 42 69 24 68 56 01 32 56 71 37 02 36 91`
>   `22 31 16 71 51 67 63 89 41 92 36 54 22 40 40 28 66 33 13 80`
>   `24 47 32 60 99 03 45 02 44 75 33 53 78 36 84 20 35 17 12 50`
>   `32 98 81 28 64 23 67 10`**26**`38 40 67 59 54 70 66 18 38 64 70`
>   `67 26 20 68 02 62 12 20 95`**63**`94 39 63 08 40 91 66 49 94 21`
>   `24 55 58 05 66 73 99 26 97 17`**78**`78 96 83 14 88 34 89 63 72`
>   `21 36 23 09 75 00 76 44 20 45 35`**14**`00 61 33 97 34 31 33 95`
>   `78 17 53 28 22 75 31 67 15 94 03 80 04 62 16 14 09 53 56 92`
>   `16 39 05 42 96 35 31 47 55 58 88 24 00 17 54 24 36 29 85 57`
>   `86 56 00 48 35 71 89 07 05 44 44 37 44 60 21 58 51 54 17 58`
>   `19 80 81 68 05 94 47 69 28 73 92 13 86 52 17 77 04 89 55 40`
>   `04 52 08 83 97 35 99 16 07 97 57 32 16 26 26 79 33 27 98 66`
>   `88 36 68 87 57 62 20 72 03 46 33 67 46 55 12 32 63 93 53 69`
>   `04 42 16 73 38 25 39 11 24 94 72 18 08 46 29 32 40 62 76 36`
>   `20 69 36 41 72 30 23 88 34 62 99 69 82 67 59 85 74 04 36 16`
>   `20 73 35 29 78 31 90 01 74 31 49 71 48 86 81 16 23 57 05 54`
>   `01 70 54 71 83 51 54 69 16 92 33 48 61 43 52 01 89 19 67 48`
>
> The product of these numbers is 26 × 63 × 78 × 14 = 1788696.
>
> What is the greatest product of four adjacent numbers in the same direction (up, down, left, right, or diagonally) in the 20×20 grid?

with the following Python code:

```
import itertools
import numpy as np

GRID = [
    [8, 2, 22, 97, 38, 15, 0, 40, 0, 75, 4, 5, 7, 78, 52, 12, 50, 77, 91, 8],
    [49, 49, 99, 40, 17, 81, 18, 57, 60, 87, 17, 40, 98, 43, 69, 48, 4, 56, 62, 0],
    [81, 49, 31, 73, 55, 79, 14, 29, 93, 71, 40, 67, 53, 88, 30, 3, 49, 13, 36, 65],
    [52, 70, 95, 23, 4, 60, 11, 42, 69, 24, 68, 56, 1, 32, 56, 71, 37, 2, 36, 91],
    [22, 31, 16, 71, 51, 67, 63, 89, 41, 92, 36, 54, 22, 40, 40, 28, 66, 33, 13, 80],
    [24, 47, 32, 60, 99, 3, 45, 2, 44, 75, 33, 53, 78, 36, 84, 20, 35, 17, 12, 50],
    [32, 98, 81, 28, 64, 23, 67, 10, 26, 38, 40, 67, 59, 54, 70, 66, 18, 38, 64, 70],
    [67, 26, 20, 68, 2, 62, 12, 20, 95, 63, 94, 39, 63, 8, 40, 91, 66, 49, 94, 21],
    [24, 55, 58, 5, 66, 73, 99, 26, 97, 17, 78, 78, 96, 83, 14, 88, 34, 89, 63, 72],
    [21, 36, 23, 9, 75, 0, 76, 44, 20, 45, 35, 14, 0, 61, 33, 97, 34, 31, 33, 95],
    [78, 17, 53, 28, 22, 75, 31, 67, 15, 94, 3, 80, 4, 62, 16, 14, 9, 53, 56, 92],
    [16, 39, 5, 42, 96, 35, 31, 47, 55, 58, 88, 24, 0, 17, 54, 24, 36, 29, 85, 57],
    [86, 56, 0, 48, 35, 71, 89, 7, 5, 44, 44, 37, 44, 60, 21, 58, 51, 54, 17, 58],
    [19, 80, 81, 68, 5, 94, 47, 69, 28, 73, 92, 13, 86, 52, 17, 77, 4, 89, 55, 40],
    [4, 52, 8, 83, 97, 35, 99, 16, 7, 97, 57, 32, 16, 26, 26, 79, 33, 27, 98, 66],
    [88, 36, 68, 87, 57, 62, 20, 72, 3, 46, 33, 67, 46, 55, 12, 32, 63, 93, 53, 69],
    [4, 42, 16, 73, 38, 25, 39, 11, 24, 94, 72, 18, 8, 46, 29, 32, 40, 62, 76, 36],
    [20, 69, 36, 41, 72, 30, 23, 88, 34, 62, 99, 69, 82, 67, 59, 85, 74, 4, 36, 16],
    [20, 73, 35, 29, 78, 31, 90, 1, 74, 31, 49, 71, 48, 86, 81, 16, 23, 57, 5, 54],
    [1, 70, 54, 71, 83, 51, 54, 69, 16, 92, 33, 48, 61, 43, 52, 1, 89, 19, 67, 48]
]

def diagonals(matrix):
    '''
    Returns all diagonals from a matrix
    '''
    # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313308/get-all-the-diagonals-in-a-matrix-list-of-lists-in-python
    np_array = np.array(matrix)
    diags = [np_array[::-1, :].diagonal(i).tolist() for
             i in range(-np_array.shape[0]+1, np_array.shape[1])]
    diags.extend(np_array.diagonal(i).tolist() for
                 i in range(np_array.shape[1]-1, -np_array.shape[0], -1))
    return diags

def columns(matrix):
    '''
    Returns all columns from a matrix
    '''
    np_array = np.array(matrix)
    cols = [np_array[:, i].tolist() for i in range(np_array.shape[1])]
    return cols

def subsequences(lst, size):
    '''
    Returns all subsequences of certain size from a list
    '''
    # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6670828/find-all-consecutive-sub-sequences-of-length-n-in-a-sequence
    return [list(subsequence) for subsequence in zip(*(lst[i:] for i in range(size)))]

def largest_adjacent_product(matrix, subsequence_size):
    '''
    Returns largest product of a subsequence of a certain size of adjacent
    numbers of a matrix. The subsequences can be horizontal, vertical and
    diagonal.
    '''
    diags = diagonals(matrix)
    cols = columns(matrix)

    horizontal_subsequences = itertools.chain.from_iterable(
        [subsequences(row, subsequence_size) for row in matrix])

    diagonal_subsequences = itertools.chain.from_iterable(
        [subsequences(diag, subsequence_size) for diag in diags])

    vertical_subsequences = itertools.chain.from_iterable(
        [subsequences(col, subsequence_size) for col in cols])

    horizontal_products = [np.prod(subsequence) for
                           subsequence in horizontal_subsequences]

    diagonal_products = [np.prod(subsequence) for
                         subsequence in diagonal_subsequences]

    vertical_products = [np.prod(subsequence) for
                         subsequence in vertical_subsequences]

    max_horizontal_product = max(horizontal_products)
    max_diagonal_product = max(diagonal_products)
    max_vertical_product = max(vertical_products)

    result = max(max_horizontal_product, max_diagonal_product, max_vertical_product)

    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(largest_adjacent_product(GRID, 4))
```

So, what are your thoughts?

Comment: I don't see great problems.  In `largest_adjecent_product` you have some repetitions going on. Maybe you could introduce a function for the subsequences and directly concat them instead of repeating the same code three times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at `largest_adjacent_product` you should see that `{}_subsequences`, `{}_products` and `max_{}_product` are all created the same way.
If you make it its own function, and add `subsequences`, then you should be able to come to:

```
product = np.prod
chain = itertools.chain.from_iterable
max(product(s) for s in chain(zip(*(row[i:] for i in range(size))) for row in grid))
```

You can actually remove the `chain`.
This gives you code that is easy to read:

```
product = np.prod
max(product(s)
    for row in grid
    for s in zip(*(row[i:] for i in range(size))))
```

Alternately I'd use use the second answer for `subsequence` and use:

```
product = np.prod
max(product(row[i:i + size])
    for row in grid
    for i in range(len(row) - size + 1))
```

I'd say this is better,
space complexity is \$O(1)\$, as opposed to \$O(kn)\$ (or \$O(k\sqrt{n})\$ for the modified ones above).
Time complexity should be the same at \$O(kn)\$,
and the readability of both the above are much better.
\$k =\$ size and \$n =\$ grid.

This would make your code much simpler:

```
def largest_subset(grid, size):
    product = np.prod
    return max(product(row[i:i + size])
               for row in grid
               for i in range(len(row) - size + 1))

def largest_adjacent_product(matrix, size):
    return max(largest_subset(i, size)
               for i in [matrix, columns(matrix), diagonals(matrix)])
```

I don't like how you change `matrix` to `np_array` in both diagonals and columns.
I would use `grid` rather than both terms, and just overwrite `grid` when converted to a np array.
Alternately I'd pass both a np array in the first place.